# How to get the id of an iframe from inside the iframe window itself?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension and I have my injected script which runs at all frames on the page. So I am able to enter every iframe of the page. 
So when I am in the iframe I need to get the ID of the particular iframe itself from within the window of the iframe. 
I have tried this

```
window.frameElement // it shows null 
window.frameElement.id
```

In any case, here is my manifest.json and I am running the code in **js/sub.js**

```
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name":"No-one",
  "description":"Hold the door",
  "version":"1.0",
  "icons": { "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png" },
  "browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"images/icon.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "permissions":[
    "tabs","background","storage","notifications","webRequest", "webRequestBlocking","<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts":[
    {
      "js":["js/content_script.js"],
      "matches":["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at": "document_start"

    },
    {"js": ["js/sub.js"], "matches": ["<all_urls>"], "all_frames":true}
  ],
  "background":{
    "scripts":["js/background.js"],
    "persistent":true
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "web_accessible_resources": ["css/own_modal.css","css/bootstrap.css" ,"css/onHover.css", "js/second_scr.js","images/icon.png","images/icon2.png","images/icon2.jpg"]

}
```

Basically, I want to take **a** tag of every iframe of the page and then show to which Div this **a** tag belongs. 
That's why I have to get into every iframe,get the **a** tag and ID of the frame, post the message. 
So how can I get the id of the iframe from within the iframe if its possible?
If its not possible,then could you suggest me some other way so that I can get  tag of the iframe and tell to which div this **a** tag belongs? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: any solution to this? @vishal sharma